# How to re-reun a specific pytest test, based on output error

Tags: python, appium, pytest, allure, pytest-mock

Say if appium throws webdriver exception error, only then that specific test should re-run in pytest

Comment: `pytest --lf` will rerun all tests that failed in the previous run (`lf` = "last failed"). `pytest --lf -x` will rerun only the first test that has failed in the previous run. If you want to run a specific test, pass its node ID as parameter, e.g. `pytest tests/test_module.py::test_func_name`. The node IDs of the failed tests are printed in a special section at the end of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pytest-rerunfailures](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-rerunfailures) library to achieve this. It is a plugin for pytest.

Following are the requirements to use it.

> Python 3.6, up to 3.8, or PyPy3

> pytest 5.0 or newer

Once installed you can pass `--only-rerun` argument with pytest and re-run the specific failed test.

```
$ pytest --reruns 5 --only-rerun AssertionError
```